WLS: Connections Leaked - inactive sessions are not closed, despite of Inactive Connection Timeout
I have a Java web application running with the following setup:

Java Web application
Oracle WebLogic (14.1.1.)
Oracle Database

We have noticed that the DB User (Schema) seems to have leaked connections - the count of inactive sessions (going up to several 1000) and do not get closed.
The Connection Pool has a configured capacity of 100. (not 1000)
After some time it is needed to restart the WebLogic application instance to free the resources.
I checked the Configuration of the Data Source, and found the 'Inactive Connection Timeout'. Even when this is enabled (e.g. set to 60) it seems to has no effect on the leaked resources (contrary to what the description says about it).
My question is: What else can I do to get the inactive connections closed? From data source or WL side?
PS: I can not directly change the application. But de-compiled it and found the location where the access to the DB is leaking (seems to be one method) - but this is containing proper closing of the connection (normal and for exceptions, it is an .getVendorConnection()).
